# Visual C++ Program Created by Appwizard stopped working

Tags: visual-c++

I have an old program that stopped working some years ago that I think is written in Microsoft Visual Studio 2006.
I have the source code and I really would like it working again.
Anyone have any idea where to start.
Should I download M Visual 2006 and try to rebuild it with appwizard or can I convert it to visual 2016 edition?
I have never worked with visual c++ so I need help by you guys

Comment: The *program* stopped working? Why that? Have you been using a different OS? VS doesn't mind if your *program* is from 2006 or from 2016.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft Visual Studio 2006`, or `2016`... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by installing Visual Studio. Use the new version because you want to use a version with the latest bug fixes.

With that large of a difference in version numbers, there a chance you'll see some some errors show up.

You just need to do it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Downloads | Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) and click on "Download Community Free". You will get some awesome software for free that previously might have cost you $1000 (the same edition, just a newer version that is now free).

Assuming you have the solution (sln) file and associated files, just open the project using the solution file to open it. Hopefully VS will convert everything for you. Be sure to have a copy of everything, but it is unlikely that would be necessary.

If VS is unable to open and convert the solution then the next step is to try "File" | "New" | "Project From Existing Code". It is not especially easy to say what to do next, since it depends on the project, but that would be the next thing to try. If you need help with it then be sure to be as specific as possible about what type of project it is and such (in a new question) but there is a good chance that VS will do everything for you simply by opening the project.